# Get text of specific anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the `text()` value of an anchor tag I have clicked from a set of anchor tags. This code below gets all the text value of the anchor tags:

```
$('#search-helper-container, .search-match a').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var test = $(this).find('a').text();
            console.log(test);
        });
```

How can I modify if so that I get only the text value of the anchor tag I click? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/tj5YQ/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the click handler to the anchor elements with class `search-match` which are inside the container `#search-helper-container`. So you need to change the selector as given below then `this` inside the click handler will refer to the clicked anchor element.

```
$('#search-helper-container a.search-match').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = $(this).text();
    console.log(test);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bm5zC/)

Comment: does not work for me it returns all text from the div

Comment: @a_miguel6687 - sorry fixed that... there was a problem with the selector also - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bm5zC/1/

Comment: follow-up question does this work inside a jquery plugin? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @a_miguel6687 yes.. it should... can you share some more details about the plugin...

Comment: The one reason could that the anchor elements are created dynamically... in that case use event delegation like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bm5zC/2/